# Node spawn child process not working in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, spawn

I have a simple script setup using spawn on windows and its output is:

```
spawn error: Error: spawn dir ENOENT
spawn child process closed with code -4058
```

Here's the code:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const spawnTest = (() => {
  const dir = spawn('dir');

  dir.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`spawn stdout: ${data}`);
  });

  dir.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`spawn stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  dir.on('error', (code) => {
    console.log(`spawn error: ${code}`);
  });

  dir.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`spawn child process closed with code ${code}`);
  });

  dir.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`spawn child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 10):

You need the `shell: true` option for `spawn()` as in `spawn('dir', {shell: true});`.

This code works as expected on Windows:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const spawnTest = (() => {
  const dir = spawn('dir', {shell: true});       // <== shell: true option

  dir.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`spawn stdout: ${data}`);
  });

  dir.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`spawn stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  dir.on('error', (code) => {
    console.log(`spawn error: ${code}`);
  });

  dir.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`spawn child process closed with code ${code}`);
  });

  dir.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`spawn child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
})();
```

My guess here is that because `dir` is not an actual program (there's no `dir.exe` in Windows), you have to tell the `spawn()` command whether it's supposed to run this in a command shell or without a command shell.  Whereas on other platforms, things such as `ls` are actual programs that can be run either way.